# Copy msu/cab files to Windows directories without installing

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I have all the Windows 7 updates as msu or cab files. I can install them using `dism /online /addpackage`, but I don't want to do that.

I want to install updates from `Windows Update` but I want to use the msu / cab files I had.

Is there any way that I can copy the msu / cab files to Windows directories without actually installing updates,  So that when I check for (and install) updates using `Windows Update` it actually uses those local files..??

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible and makes no sense for me. Ether install them with WUSA (double click o the MSU) or via DISM (for the CAB) if Windows Update is too slow to install the updates.

Comment: I don't want to install expired , superseded updates. And I don't think the manual methods are intelligent enough to track them.

Comment: WUSA already checks if the update is superseded and if yes, it shows "Update doesn't apply"

Comment: is your question answered or do you need more information?